# Cannot install pipenv through terminal (Python)

Tags: python, terminal, pipenv, virtual-environment

I am currently following the Learn Python-course on Codecademy. At some point you are taught how to create virtual environments via pipenv. This video shows how to install pipenv: ["Python Walkthrough Virtual Environments with Pipenv"](https://youtu.be/BVr-6Ki96XM). However, I am having the following problem:

When following the step-by-step instruction, after having installed pipenv, once I restart Terminal and type `pipenv --version`, I still get the following error message: `zsh: command not found: pipenv`. None of the exising threads in the codecademy forums have been helpful and neither have been Google searches.

When I open my bash_profile, it looks as follows: [image: bash_profile]

What I noticed when following the instructions to install pipenv was that my bash_profile file already contained several lines of text, whereas the instructor’s file seemed to be empty. Can anyone recognize from the screenshot if I did anything wrong when installing or if the preexisting lines have something to do with my problem?

Another piece of information, that may help: when I type `echo $PATH`, this is what I get: [image: echo $PATH]

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error says you're using z shell so that bash_profile is not the applicable. There should be a `.zshrc` in your home folder. That is your profile.

Also, you might just need to restart your shell. Try:

`exec $SHELL`

in your terminal. Then try pipenv.

Comment: Apologies for being dense, but could you instruct me on how to find and how to use that zshrc file?

As for the second part of your answer: I hav dond that, I still receive the same error message.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ollie's answer above, I've found the solution. It is basically just an explanation of what to do after following Ollie's advice:

There indeed was a `.zshrc` folder in my home folder. To find out, I had to restart terminal and list all the contents of my home directory using `ls -a`, which lists all files in the currently active directory *including hidden files*.

So, quite simply: instead of opening `bash_profile` to add the relevant PATH to, I had to open this `.zshrc` file and paste it there. Everything worked smoothly thereafter.